# What's an easy way to move all my development applications/settings to a new computer?

Tags: windows-10, development

Over time, I'd installed a lot of applications on my (former) work machine. Node, various PHP installations, composer, eclipse (and plugins), vs code, GIT and much more. I've lost track of everything I've installed to be honest. In fact, it got so bad that I refused a change to faster machine because I didn't have the time to go through everything and set up a new system. I've left that job now and have started a new one.

I've been given a machine here and been told that I'll be getting a new one in a few days and that these guys have a semi regular upgrade/change schedule. Meanwhile, I'm getting this (kinda shitty) machine set up. I don't want to be locked into the same problem again. How can I set it up in such a way that I can basically move all my stuff (possibly including PATH variables) to a new machine as painlessly as possible? I'm open to both free and paid solutions, depending of efficacy. I'd rather not install and tweak dozens of applications and plugins every year. If a cross platform solution is possible, that'd be even better, since it'd prevent OS lock in.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third-party software can migrate applications, profiles, settings and files to a new Windows PC, but you may need to pay for it or take a risk.

Such as Zinstall’s WinWin, LapLink "PC Mover or EaseUS "Todo PCTrans."

If you want to use Microsoft’s product, User State Migration Tool looks good.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/usmt/getting-started-with-the-user-state-migration-tool